# Android Display .Doc File in WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview, doc

In my app,I have link http://mymobilece.com/api/api_getexammaterials.php?id=28,
I want to view in webview ,I try with  google document viewer its work fine But i need it without google document viewer,How to show it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the js for google Doc viever

```
myScript="<html><iframe src='http://docs.google.com/gview?

url='http://mymobilece.com/api/api_getexammaterials.php?

id=28'&embedded='true' style='width:600px; height:500px;' 

frameborder='0'></iframe></html>"

mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadData(myscript,"text/html", "UTF-8");
```

you can use myscript as string variable and use this javascript code(please make sure to remove double quite if above code) and load in webview

- You can change the url - width- height variables according to your scripting.

Comment: read question carefully...its works already in my app....but not using google doc...

Answer (score 1):

Docs.google.com has a document parser , which basically parses MS-Office files , thats why you can view it on google docs. without that you will have to write document parser. Which will parse files and fetch the contents to display on view. In Short it will be not a good idea to do that. :)