# how to read pdf and doc file from asset into webview in android?

Tags: android

```
File file=new File("file:///android_asset"+filename);

if (file.exists()) {
        Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");
            try {
                startActivity(intent1);
            } 
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(FileWebView.this, 
                     "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: Please check this [link][1] . You can use google doc viewer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8240737/614807

Comment: Could you please provide a little more information, i.e. how that the code in the activity look, that handles the Intent, what exactly happens, do any error occur, logcat output (if there are some messages related to this) etc.

Comment: its showing blank screen without any error..