# Unable to open Url from server of office files (xlxs , doc , txt) in default app android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fileprovider

Currently working on handling of multiple type of files and allowing them to open with there default app in android phone.
As far till now i am able to open all others file like : pdf,image,audio with there default app installed in the phone.
but when t comes to office files like xlxs, doc.
Already installed OFFICE SUITE but i was unable to open them.

**Code to open with its default app:**

```
@Override
public void onSelectedItem(String image_urls_, int position) {
String mimeType = getMimeType(image_urls_);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(image_urls_), mimeType);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Log.e("memtype", mimeType);
try {
startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
Toast.makeText(Attachments.this, "No handler for this type of file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Log.e("bug_file", e.toString());
 }
}
```

**code to find out type of file**

```
public static String getMimeType(String url) {
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        type = 
    MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to download file first and then assign a local path to intent .

Comment: can u please guide how to achieve that. @ADM

Comment: Well you can Simply use `DownloadManager` for downloading.

Comment: okk thank you will try as you said . @ADM

Comment: Instead of Download you can show them up in WebView https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797706/2599596

Answer (score 0):

I used WebView and ImageView to show the documents in inside app itself.

**xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/attachment"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.attachement_detail_activity);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        View rlImage = findViewById(R.id.rl_image);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image_view);

        fileUrl = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
        courseName = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_COURSE_TITLE);
        courseId = getIntent().getIntExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_COURSE_ID, 0);
        if(fileUrl.contains(".jpg") || fileUrl.contains(".jpeg") || fileUrl.contains(".png")) {
            AQuery aQuery = new AQuery(this);
            aQuery.id(imageView).progress(R.id.progress_bar).image(fileUrl, false, true, Helper.getDisplayWidth(this), 0);
            rlImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            rlImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            showDoc(fileUrl);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void showDoc(final String fileUrl){
        if (Helper.isConnected(this)) {
            final Dialog progressDialog = new Dialog(this);
            if (progressDialog.getWindow() != null) {
                progressDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            }
            progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_layout);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setTitle(this.getString(R.string.app_name));

            if (progressDialog.getWindow() != null) {
                progressDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                progressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            }
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    progressDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
//            String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
            webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + fileUrl);
        }
    }
```

Here I used Android Query Library to show image from URL [library](https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery)

If you want to use download after view this file, you can provide download option to user to download. Use download manager to download the file from url [how to use download manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5879563/2599596)