# No Activity found to handle Intent whien trying to open word file or excel file

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent

"here i want to open file "

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(docList[position]?.image), docList[position]?.contentType)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
startActivity(holder.itemView.context, intent, null)
```

Comment: val intent = Intent()
                        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(docList[position]?.image), docList[position]?.contentType)
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                        startActivity(holder.itemView.context, intent, null)

Comment: check my above code

Comment: Please post your code in a normal code block. And remove that comment with code for a second time.

Comment: Post an example of the `Uri` - seems odd you are referencing a field named `.image` in your `docList` ?  And post `contentType`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've the same problem, i got the same error while both of excel and google sheets are installed

Answer (score -1):

if you get ActivityNotFound exception it means there is no application in your device to support this file type.

first of all wrap your code in **try/catch** block to prevent crash.

then you have some options :

first way : you can open play store to prompt user to download office app

```
try{
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(docList[position]?.image),
                docList[position]?.contentType)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        startActivity(holder.itemView.context, intent, null)
    }
        catch(e:ActivityNotFoundException){

            //NOTE: you can show toast to user or open google play store for required app

            startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.microsoft.office.officehubrow")))

        }
```

second way : you can use android **WebView** to show excel / word file types in your app without Intent

check this:

[How to open Excel, .doc files in Webview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797651/how-to-open-excel-doc-files-in-webview-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

```
val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(docList[position]?.image), docList[position]?.contentType)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    if (intent.resolveActivity(requireActivity().packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(holder.itemView.context, intent, null)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "No Application available to handle this intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

Use resolveActivity method of intent. it will return app which can handle this intent else it will be null.

Comment: What is the purpuse? What resolveActivity does?