# Android Office Files Viewer(pptx, doc , txt , .xls ) Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dependencies, powerpoint, ms-office, doc

Does anyone know how to view these files from kotlin code, i dont know the dependency also , pdf is easily method but i dont know about these, just give mw knowledge how to do it in kotlin

to show the docs, ppt, files to user and edit some information

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797651/how-to-open-excel-doc-files-in-webview-in-android check this out